# Substitute the values of one python pandas dataframe column by values from another based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

dt=pd.DataFrame({'schoolNum':['12','13','14','13'],'oldDistrict':['A','B', 'C','B'],'newDistrict':['F',' ','G',' ']})

dt=pd.DataFrame({'schoolNum':['12','13','14','13'],'oldDistrict':['A','B', 'C','B'],'newDistrict':['F','B','G','B']})
```

I tried:

```
dt.ix[dt['oldDistrict']=='13', 'newDistrict']=dt.oldDistrict
```

But I get an error message that is something about axis.

Comment: Are you trying to replace blank values, or replace values associated with particular values in the "schoolNum" column, per the example of what you tried?

Comment: Yes, at this time I am trying to replace the missing (blank) values. But occasionally I also have to deal with non missing values, which changed at some point in time.

Comment: I ask because A-Za-z's answer has limited use cases, even though it works for your mini example here. The .loc method is more aligned with what you asked ("Substitute the values of one python pandas dataframe column by values from another based on a condition") and offers far more flexibility for dealing with future cases, including blank values, i.e. (dt.loc[dt['newDistrict']==' ', 'newDistrict'] = dt['oldDistrict']).

Comment: Thank you. I'll try the .loc method tomorrow. Today I had to replace the missing observations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can replace the blanks by np.nan and then use combine_first

```
dt = dt.replace({' ': np.nan})
dt['newDistrict'] = dt['newDistrict'].combine_first(dt['oldDistrict'])
```

Returns

```
    newDistrict oldDistrict schoolNum
0   F           A           12
1   B           B           13
2   G           C           14
3   B           B           13
```

Comment: You are welcome, you can consider accepting the answer :)

Comment: I also forgotten how to do that, but now I remembered :) #longtimenotaround

Answer (score 1):

Two things:

1. You want to use .loc instead of .ix:

   ```
   dt.loc[<condition>, <column(s) returned>]
   ```
2. 'oldDistrict' has no values equal to "13" - those are in "schoolNum". So what you want in full is:

   ```
   dt.loc[dt['schoolNum']=='13', 'newDistrict'] = dt['oldDistrict']
   ```